# how to make height responsive screens in ionic 2?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, responsive

I know we can make horizontally responsive content in ionic 2. What i want to know is how to make pages height responsive for all type of screens for example if a screen cover whole area on iphone 5 then it should cover whole height wisie area in iphone 7 also ? whats the best approach to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

As some have already mentioned, you can use `vh` for the height property on your css. The catch here is that the `viewport` may change even if the screen orientation stays the same. This happens when you place an `input` in your app and it gets focus. The keyboard of the mobile device pops up on the screen, and the height of the viewport changes because the keyboard took part of it. f your mobile screen is **430x710** (some random number here) **1vh** would be **7.1px**, but when you tap on an input and lets say the keyboard is ***430x300***, now **1vh** will be **4.1px**  (( **710** - ***300*** )/100)

That could be a real problem with responsive design. My advice is to use **vw**, the only thing that might alter it is the screen orientation (you can lock it). The extra step is that you have to use conversion to get the right number in **vw** that you wanted previously in **vh**.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your question correctly, you want to make the page height the same as the height of the device viewing it?

Well, let me introduce you to....

**viewport height (or vh)**

One vh is equal to 1% of the height of the viewport. So, as you can probably imagine, 100vh would be equal to 100% of the height of the viewport! The viewport is basically the view of the page. However *beware*, the vh unit is not support in Internet Explorer 8 or earlier.

Comment: is this supported in ionic 2 ?

Comment: @WaleedShabbir Viewport height is native to CSS/HTML, it will work with or without ionic 2.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you will get good idea to make the responsive properly from the follow parameters.

**vw: 1/100th** viewport width

**vh: 1/100th** viewport height

**vmin: 1/100th** of the smallest side

**vmax: 1/100th** of the largest side

Actually vh is a perfect solution to make the responsive based on viewporot. The viewport is the area where the browser renders the site. This is your screen minus the reserved space of the browser chrome. Sometimes you want to size an element based on that viewport, like a sidebar. This can be done using a unit we’re all familiar with: percentages.